# Mega menu how to change direction?

Tags: html, css

I have mega menu with normal display direction. But with two last obcjects i want it to show drom that button to up. I don't know how to describe it.
I want something like that:

```
            subobject3
            subobject2
    object> subobject1
```

Comment: **I don't know how to describe it.**, Than how will explain it?

Comment: And what is "mega menu"? Care to show some code or at least link to what you're using?

Comment: http://gracja.worldbit.pl this is that page. (Look at the "Oferta) i want Last 3 things to show from down to up.

Comment: Somebody know what i have to do?

Comment: @Kernelus how can we understand your question if you are not able to explain what you want? You see the problem?

Comment: Can u draw us picture what exactly u want to have? :D I think we don't really know what you want.

Comment: I think I got it. Do you mean you want to display the submenus of the last two items of the `Oferta` menu with its bottom item at the height of the hovered menu item instead of its top item?

Comment: I think the point is that the last few items of the secondary menu hang down very low on the page, so instead of hanging down, the OP wants them to start from the hovered list item and point upwards. I've answered on that assumption below, anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one drop menu under Oferta, which has a secondary drop menu. Towards the bottom of the primary drop down list, the secondary list sits very low on the page, and I assume the question is how to make the last few secondary items point upwards rather than downwards.

An easy way to do that is to give the bottom few list items in the primary drop list a class (say "upwards") and then do this in the CSS:

```
li.submenu.upwards:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;  /* bottom instead of top */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first, sorry for my bad English !

- your menu can be simpler, you have many duplicated CSS ids & ... !

however, this is simplest fix for you:

past this line to your CSS:

```
.menu5 {margin:-170px 0 0 0;}
```

and in your HTML find:

```
<a href="zdrowotne.html"></a>
    <ul>
```

replace with:

```
<a href="zdrowotne.html"></a>
    <ul class="menu5">
```

you can use this method for other items as same as use here, just by make  class.

At the end, again sorry for my bad English.